# Verify Sha256Rsa message

Tags: rsa, openssl, certificate

I have a plaintext, rsaSignature (in hex)
and a cert (.cer)

How can i verify the rsasignature with the plaintext and cert given.

I know that i am required to extract the public key from the cert.

I do not know how to continue from here.

How can i sign the message so that i can compare with the sha256RSA signature that was provided

Comment: I know how to get the pubkey

Comment: Try this: `openssl dgst -sha256 -verify <pubkey.pem> -signature <signaturefile> <originalfile>`

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - Questions about how to use a piece of software are actually off-topic here, even if that software uses cryptography. I can migrate your question to a more appropriate site for you.

Comment: @Lorinczy (don't know if ping works on migrated)+ `dgst -verify` requires the signature as raw (often called binary) not hex. (So do `pkeyutl` and `rsautl`.) In some Unix shells this can be converted on the fly like `-signature <(xxd -r -p hexfile)` or `-signature <(echo $hexdata | xxd -r -p)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify what code/command you used to get the signature/plaintext/cert I suggest you follow [this](https://sandilands.info/sgordon/public-key-encryption-and-digital-signatures-using-openssl), ask again in detail if you got stuck.